# nginx deny to allow a single IP

Tags: nginx, whitelist

I'm trying to set up an nginx config that allows only one source IP to access `/admin`.

I tried the following `nginx.conf`:

```
user root;

events {
}

http {
  server {
    listen       5000;

    location /admin {
      allow 1.2.3.4;
      deny all;
      return 200;
    }
  }
}
```

**What I was expecting:**

Only requests originating from `1.2.3.4` would receive the 200 OK response. Other requests would receive a 403 Unauthorised.

**What I'm seeing:**

Regardless of the source IP, I'm getting a 200 OK response.

```
$ docker run -it -v /tmp/test/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 nginx:alpine
...
$ curl localhost:5000/admin -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /admin HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.15.11
< Date: Sun, 14 Apr 2019 20:33:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
```

How can I whitelist a certain IP address for a path in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is processed in the nginx rewrite [phase](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases), which is before the access phase where access control is checked.

To solve the problem, put in a real configuration for your virtual server instead of a "test" configuration. For instance, set a document `root` and put an `index.html` file in it, or `proxy_pass` to a web application.